# RoR: Rake failing - "Not a git repository : .git" & "Could not find activesupport-4.2.3 in any of the sources"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rake

UPDATE 2: This gem is definitely causing the git errors as well. In the gemspec files it has git commands which when I commented out, got rid of the git errors.

UPDATE 1: So after uninstalling ruby and all gems and going back through and reinstalling I found the source of at least one of the issues. The devise-neo4j gemfile.lock requires version 4.2.3 of `activesupport` and all other rails gems. Currently looking to see if there's a fix. Not sure if that is also causing the weird git errors but they seemed to crop up at the exact same time.

ORIGINAL POST:

When running any rake command I get the following error :

`` fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Could not find activesupport-4.2.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems. ``

Which makes no sense because when I run `git status` I get:

`On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean`

and I also have active support installed so I have no idea whats happening:

`C:\Users\mcr43\RubymineProjects\Carbon>bundle show activesupport
D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1`

I've tried looking for a solution via other people with similar issues but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Are you using any gems pointing to a local path? I've seen that `Not a git repository` warning when a gem is copied to a local path without its .git directory, but the gemspec uses a git command to list the gem's files.

Comment: Not that I know of. I went through my gem and gem lock and none of them were pointing to a local path.

Answer (score 0):

Where do run a rake command. in development or in production? In development it should not have anything to do with git. Are you using rails 5+? than you can also try `rails db:migrate` instead of rake. at least in development. Did you check git remote? did you run git add . and git commit -m "com" correctly? Did you push everything into git? Can you see your app in your git folder online? Try these things and double check.

Comment: Running rake command in development mode. I'm using rails 5 and yes i checked my git remote. Everything is added and everything is pushing / committing fine

Comment: Did you try to use rails instead of rake? e,g. rails db:create, or rails db:migrate etc... This is rails5 way to do it

Comment: I was using some rake tasks from another gem. any rails command worked. It was just the rake ones that were giving the git error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `bundle install`?

You have `activesupport-5.0.1` installed, but it is looking for `activesupport-4.2.3`

Comment: Yes I ran bundle install. It doesn't change anything. is there anyway to find out what specifically is asking for the 4.2.3 version?

Answer (score 0):

So after uninstalling ruby and all gems and going back through and reinstalling I found the source of at least one of the issues. The devise-neo4j gemfile.lock requires version 4.2.3 of `activesupport` and all other rails gems. Currently looking to see if there's a fix. Not sure if that is also causing the weird git errors but they seemed to crop up at the exact same time.

UPDATE: This gem is definitely causing the git errors. In the gemspec files it has git commands which when I commented out, got rid of the git errors.